# Return results only if there are enough records

Tags: sql, oracle

Thanks in advance for your replies, this is a 2-part question.

The Database would be called: "Production"
The Table would be called: "FruitHistory"

Sample Data:

[image]

Is there a way to query this data such that it will only return results that have at least 3 day's worth of data (as an example).

Ex: The query returns Tony's, David's and Aaron's records but not Bern's

**Part2:**

Building on Part1's rule but now only returning 3 days worth of data at all

Ex: The query returns 11/3-11/5 for Tony and Aaron and all of David's data but still not Bern's.

Thanks!

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?

Comment: There are  no Aaron rows in your sample data.

Comment: Also, the second column does not appear to be any date format I have seen before.  It looks like maybe you copied this out of Excel, but the formatting got messed up.

Comment: which database? is there a date field?

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc, etc, etc??

Comment: You need better sample data. For example add someone with 3 rows, where 2 of them are on the same date.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempts.

Comment: Brad: Oracle SQL Developer
Jarlh: Added, ty
Tim: I did copy out of excel, the dates are 11/5/18-11/1/18 in descending order
Karthik: There is a datefield
MatBailie: Oracle
jarlh: that is not the way my data is structured?  Each person will only have 1 record per date

Comment: *3 days worth of data*: consecutive dates (3,4,5) or just three different dates(1,2,5)?

Comment: Which 3 days? (If there are several to chose from.)

Comment: OK, Oracle. What version? If it's Oracle 12.1 or higher, the problem has a very easy and efficient solution with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the DBMS you're using is relatively modern it will have analytic / windowed functions.  In which case the following should do the type of thing you describe.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*)     OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name)                           AS cust_record_count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY day_column DESC)  AS cust_record_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  summarised
WHERE
      cust_record_count >= 3
  AND cust_record_id    <= 3
```

Comment: @mathguy Could you add a `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` answer?  I need to expose myself to the good side of Oracle :)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12.1 or higher, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` can do quick work of such requirements. I create the sample data in a `WITH` clause (not part of the SQL statement - use your actual table and column names). I changed the column names - column names should not have spaces in them (your first column does), and they shouldn't be Oracle keywords (like DAY or DATE). I didn't order the output in any way; if this is the final report, not used in further processing, you can add an ORDER BY clause at the end.

```
with
  sample_data(customer, dt, fruit) as (
    select 'Tony' , date '2018-11-01', 'Orange'     from dual union all
    select 'Tony' , date '2018-11-02', 'Apple'      from dual union all
    select 'Tony' , date '2018-11-03', 'Pear'       from dual union all
    select 'Tony' , date '2018-11-04', 'Plum'       from dual union all
    select 'Tony' , date '2018-11-05', 'Grape'      from dual union all
    select 'David', date '2018-11-03', 'Orange'     from dual union all
    select 'David', date '2018-11-04', 'Watermelon' from dual union all
    select 'David', date '2018-11-05', 'Cantelope'  from dual union all
    select 'Bern' , date '2018-11-05', 'Kiwi'       from dual union all
    select 'Aaron', date '2018-11-01', 'Orange'     from dual union all
    select 'Aaron', date '2018-11-02', 'Apple'      from dual union all
    select 'Aaron', date '2018-11-03', 'Watermelon' from dual union all
    select 'Aaron', date '2018-11-04', 'Kiwi'       from dual union all
    select 'Aaron', date '2018-11-05', 'Pear'       from dual
  )
select *
from   sample_data
match_recognize (
    partition by customer
    order by     dt desc
    all rows per match
    pattern      ( ^ a{3} )
    define       a as null is null
)
;
```

**Output**:

```
CUSTOMER  DT          FRUIT
--------  ----------  -------------
Aaron     2018-11-05  Pear
Aaron     2018-11-04  Kiwi
Aaron     2018-11-03  Watermelon
David     2018-11-05  Cantelope
David     2018-11-04  Watermelon
David     2018-11-03  Orange
Tony      2018-11-05  Grape
Tony      2018-11-04  Plum
Tony      2018-11-03  Pear
```

Answer (score 0):

First part:

```
SELECT Name, Count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Count(*)>2
```

Second Part:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Count(*)>2)
```

Comment: Your first part returns aggregated rows, when the OP asked for rows in the original data. Your so-called "Second Part" actually answers the OP's *first* question, but in an inefficient way. There is no answer to the second question in the OP's post. Since there is already another answer which addresses both of the OP's questions, and in the right way, this Answer gets a downvote from me (and no one will be hurt if this Answer is deleted by its author).